# issue with joins ins my query, how to populate null values as zero

Tags: sql

My query is to fetch data for last 5 weeks.

```
select z.week,
sum(case when i.severity=1 then 1 else 0 end) as 1
sum(case when i.severity=2 then 1 else 0 end) as 2
sum(case when i.severity=3 then 1 else 0 end) as 3
sum(case when i.severity=4 then 1 else 0 end) as 4
from instance as i
and left outer join year as z on convert(varchar(10),z.date,101)=convert(varchar(10),i.created,101)
and left outer join year as z on convert(varchar(10),z.date,101)=convert(varchar(10),i.closed,101)
where i.group in '%Teams%'
and z.year=2013
and z.week<=6 and z.week>1
```

here there are few weeks in my instance table, where there will be not even an single row. so here im not getting null or zero... instead the entire row is not at all prompting.

my present output.

```
week | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 
---------------------
2  | 0 | 1 | 8 | 5
3  | 2 | 3 | 4 | 9
5  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

but i need output like the below...

```
week | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 
---------------------
2  | 0 | 1 | 8 | 5
3  | 2 | 3 | 4 | 9
4  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
5  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
6  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

How to get the desired outputi n sql

Comment: What flavor of sql are you using?

Comment: Use a left join instead of a left outer join

Comment: @Kyra both are the same

Comment: Use `COALESCE()` to specify the value to use when null.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select z.week,
sum(case when i.severity=1 then 1 else 0 end) as 1
sum(case when i.severity=2 then 1 else 0 end) as 2
sum(case when i.severity=3 then 1 else 0 end) as 3
sum(case when i.severity=4 then 1 else 0 end) as 4
from year as z 
left outer join instance as i  on   
convert(varchar(10),z.date,101)=convert(varchar(10),i.created,101)
and convert(varchar(10),z.date,101)=convert(varchar(10),i.closed,101)
where (i.group is null or i.group in '%Teams%')
and z.year=2013
and z.week<=6 and z.week>1
```

Comment: i tried this, but no luck.
Here in my case, there is not sure of data to be ppresent in the instance. like there wont any row for i.created and i.closed.

Comment: @nitish, when you use left outer join even if there is no data for i.created ot i.closed it will return row from year table. Can you post some sample data from year/instance tables

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the query works where you alias `year` twice to `z`.  But, assuming that's not a problem, you can change the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`.  Or, if you don't like the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, rework the SELECT so that the `FROM` clause references the `year` table.